# How to make frameless window draggable in pywebview?

Tags: python, pywebview

I've been using pywebview lately to develop desktop applications with Flask. I wanted to use the frameless window feature and create my own title bar but the problem is I have no idea how I would go about making that frameless window draggable.

The documentation says it can be moved around by dragging any point but that is not the case for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> ### [Drag area](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/api.html#drag-area)
>
> *pywebview* window can be moved by dragging any element with the
> `pywebview-drag-region` class name. This is useful, for example, in
> frameless mode when you would like to implement a custom caption bar.
> The magic class name can be overriden by re-assigning the
> `webview.DRAG_REGION_SELECTOR constant`.

Comment: This answer is a direct copy from https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/api.html#drag-area. Next time, please properly quote the text and provide a link/attribution for the source (as I have done here). See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `pywebview-drag-region` in the element you want the window to get dragged from.

[image]