# How to make frameless window resizable and snap able in pywebview? Also src files

Tags: python, html, pywebview

Im making a pyweview desktop stand alone app and I have 2 things I cant seem to find much on. Mainly how to get it to see local src files and how to implement the windows snap feature. By that I mean the windows key + direction to snap to that side of the screen. I found a potential JS option for resizeing but have yet to test it.

[How to make frameless window draggable in pywebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57067929/how-to-make-frameless-window-draggable-in-pywebview)

This post gave me the answer to making it dragable.

All the examples I can find of it using things like images have to be done with a weblink and that works but the point of this particular project is to have it self contained so is there a way to have the html load local files?

The html is loaded through window.load_html() and in the html I have tried every file path I can think of but so far nothing works. Even using the full system path. Bellow is a simple example just replace *dots.svg* with any local image you have. if the html is loaded on its own it works just fine. If loaded though pyweview there is no image. I am still new to JS but is there maybe a way to use JS to load the image?

```
import webview

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <h1>This is dynamically loaded HTML</h1>
    <body>
        <img src="images/dots.svg"> image should be here
    </body>
</html>
"""

def load_html(window):
    window.load_html(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = webview.create_window('Load HTML Example', html=html)
    webview.start(load_html, window)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a dunce and it was how I had my folders. I was editing a copy folder not the main one so when I ran it it wouldnt update. as for the resize I found a solution here

https://awesomeopensource.com/project/DizzyduckAR/pywebview-Frameless-boilerplate

it doesn't add the half screen snap but it does add the window resize. Here is the code from it that does the resize. Its not as smooth as I was wanting but it does work.

```
#Resize Window
    def resizedrag(self):
        c = 1
        state_left = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01)
        beforex, beforey = pyautogui.position()
        beforex= str(beforex).rjust(4)
        beforey=str(beforey).rjust(4)
        # print(beforex,beforey)
        winWbefore=window.width
        winHbefore=window.height
        while True:
            a = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) & 0x8000
            if a != state_left:
                state_left = a
                print(a)
                if a != 0:
                    print('Left Button Pressed')
                else:
                    print('Left Button Released')
                    break

                
            print("running")
            afterx, aftery = pyautogui.position()
            afterx= str(afterx).rjust(4)
            aftery=str(aftery).rjust(4)
            try:
                totalx=int(beforex)-int(afterx)
                totaly=int(beforey)-int(aftery)
                print('totals',totalx,totaly)
            except:
                print('fail')
            if totalx > 0:
                print('reduce x')
              #  print(totalx*-1)
                changerx=winWbefore+(totalx*-1)
            else:
                print('expend x')
                changerx=winWbefore+(totalx*-1)
               # print(totalx*-1)
            
            if totaly > 0:
                print('reduce y')
               # print(totaly*-1)
                changerY=winHbefore+(totaly*-1)
            else:
                print('expend y')
                #print(totalx*-1)
                changerY=winHbefore+(totaly*-1)
            #
            print('changed',changerx, changerY)
            window.resize(changerx, changerY)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```